Color handling and "dim" on ConEmu with git-for-windows bash
Under git-for-windows "Git bash" (so, MinTTY), standard unix color codes are handled and I may use the "dim" option, so
echo -e "\033[1mHello\033[0mHello\033[2mHello\033[0m"

will output three "Hello"s, respectively bright, normal, and dim :

Using ConEmu, it seems that the bright is correctly interpreted, but the dim is ignored:

I checked with ConEmu colors settings but its definitely not related (the third Hello is not dim with all color preset).
However, I am not sure whether the problem is related to ConEmu or other windows terminal related issue.
How could I properly show dimmed text on ConEmu?
